# Getting Exception while generating the WebService when HashMap is passed as parameter

Tags: java, web-services, hashmap, jax-rpc

I am trying to create a webservice which takes a VO and VO contains a parameter of type Map. I wrote this simple Service and trying to create the webservice out of it. While creating the webservice I am getting exception  that its not supported.

```
 public MyVO myService(MyVO vo) {
    return vo;
}

public class VO{
  private String name;
  private Map<String, Serializable> paramsMap;  
}
```

Error Which I am getting :

The field or property  on the value type used via the service class has a data type, "java.util.Map", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.

I am not sure what's wrong with this. Any help or work around?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC4.html) shows the data types supported by JAX-RPC 1.1 and Map (and all its subclasses aren't supported).

JAX-RPC 1.1 Specification, section 5.1.3 states:

> Other standard Java classes (for
>   example: classes in the Java
>   Collection Framework) are mapped using
>   pluggable serializers and
>   deserializers. Refer to the chapter 15
>   (“Extensible Type Mapping”) for more
>   details on the pluggable serializers
>   and deserializers.

One *workaround* is to have an array of key/value pair JavaBean that you can pass through a parameter.

Example:

```
public final class KVPair<T> implements Serializable {
    private String key;
    private T value;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

And have a service that has a map of `KVPair`.

```
service.consume(KVPair[] map);
```

[IBM DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-jaxrpc1/) shows examples of mapping arrays as a Complex Type in WSDL.

Comment: Thanks Elite. But here on http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC2.html#wp83185 its mentioned that it supports HashMap etc.. I am now more confused. If we can use HashMap then also its fine. But When I am using HashMap and trying to generate the web-service it tells the same warning message mentioned in the original question. But when webservice proxy is generated its taking HashMap. I am not sure why this behaviour..

Comment: @java_enthu, you're using a JEE 1.3 documentation whereas I'm using JEE 1.4 documentation. I even downloaded the specification to quote the specification. I'm assuming you're using Apache Axis 1.4 which creates a type mapping for your HashMap (since it's Serializable).

Comment: I appreciate your quick response thanks a lot :)    Well I am using Apache Axis 1.5.5 in eclipse. with JDK 1.6. Do you think with 1.3 version of Axis2 i will be able to support Maps? (infact I couldn't download 1.3)

Comment: That's impossible: this is the last Apache Axis 1 that was released `NEWS (April 22, 2006): Axis 1.4 Final is now available!`. Where did you get Apache Axis 1.5.5?

Comment: Its here .http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi Version 1.5.5  Date 29 - May - 2011

Comment: That's Axis 2 and not Axis 1.